# TYPO3 <f:image /> nest viewhelper or use the processed image somehow for lazyload

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, viewhelper

I'm trying to imply lazyload with a specific slider, it requests the src of the image to be entered twice, once as src and second as data-lazy like this:

```
<img src="domain.com/image.png" data-lazy="domain.com/image.png">
```

with `<f:image />` I can use `data="{lazy: 'domain.com/image.png'}"` and should repeat the src of the image created with the viewhelper ... ([typo3 documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Image.html) and the inline use of [f:uri.image](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Uri/ImageViewHelper.html))

i have actually two questions:

- how do I nest f:uri.image ? this gives an error `<f:image src="{image.uid}" treatIdAsReference="1" data="{lazy: '{f:uri.image(src: {image.uid})}'}"/>`
- it should actually be the refference to the same
  image, if I nest f:uri.image would I create a second rendered image ?
  (especially because I also set width and height, but I wanted to keep the snippets simple)

the solution should work for TYPO3 v7 and v8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<img src="{f:uri.image(src : image.uid)}" data-lazy="{f:uri.image(src : image.uid)}" />
```

You don't have to use the `<f:image ..>` tag for creating the <f:uri.image ..> returns the same processed resource.

Comment: spot-on, thank you, i did not expect the viewhelper to yield the same processed image twice !!

Comment: Even though you "process" the same image twice, rest assured that it's gathering cached data, once it's processed the first time :-)

Answer (score 0):

In loop:

```
<f:for each="{MARKER}" as="file">
<img class="lazy" src=".../blank.gif" data-lazy="{f:uri.image(image: file, width:'XXXc', height:'XXXc', treatIdAsReference:1)}" alt="{file.alternative}" title="{file.title}">
</f:for>
```